# How does adding example library usage "change author's intent"?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I do not understand why [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13107175) was rejected. It adds an example, showing off the library that the author mentioned, and specifically the method that the author mentioned (`.rotate()`). How does that deviate from the author's intent?

Besides, do people ever read the comment added to edits? It's very small on the page and everyone completely ignored it. It clearly says I don't think it deviates from author's intent, which could have made someone think "oh he doesn't understand, let's explain" instead of stupidly selecting it anyway.

Comment: *"do people ever read the comment added to edits?"* No, not usually. They look at this, see you made a *giant* looking change, most of which involves code, and they reject on instinct. 90+% of the time, they're right. Not sure if yours is an edge case. I don't know diddly-squat about Python and would have had to skip that one. Don't count on all reviewers being so eager to hit the skip button. Being a subject matter expert is not required to review suggested edits. They cannot be certain that your edit was valid and that it did not contradict the author's intent.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the response. I felt like it's a reject-on-instinct too, which is why I added the comment... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does adding example library usage “change author's intent”?

Apparently it doesn't. As [@CodeGray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) pointed out in a comment, people probably just saw a change bigger than the post and "relied on instinct", not pausing the half second it takes to see what is going on.

I split the edit up in two parts to make it look smaller, both of which got accepted. Apparently it's a fine edit after all, it just *looked* wrong on first glance.

---

Maybe selecting moderators based on internet points is not the best idea. Or maybe people work for the badges and try to go through as many edits a minute as possible instead of looking at them properly. Having access to these tools on the Security SE site, I've felt this pressure of wanting to get that badge (the progress of which is shown on the review page).

Either way, this is out of scope. I just hope a SE admin reads this and at least keeps it in the back of their mind for future revisions of the system. Or someone else reads it and thinks of it when there's a discussion about the system somewhere. That's all I hope to achieve with this.

Comment: "Maybe selecting moderators based on internet points is not the best idea" - it all operates on doing the best with what is available. Having just anyone submit edits is also not the best idea, the amount of review work that needs to be done and the amount of garbage that needs to be thrown out is staggering. Sorry that your valid edit happened to be thrown out with the trash. When you reach 2k internet points that won't happen again so easily.